# Variant of Levy metric?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $F,G:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ be two cumulative distribution functions and define the following [what I think is a] metric: $d(F,G)$ is the area of the largest rectangle, with sides parallel to the axes, inscribed
between the graphs of $F$ and $G$. Has anyone seen such an object?

Update: I'll even conjecture a relationship between $d(F,G)$ and the Levy metric $L(F,G)$:
$$ d(F,G) \le L(F,G) \le \sqrt{d(F,G)}. $$

Update II: Following Gil's suggestion, here the definition of Levy metric:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_metric

In words, it's what you get if you replace "rectangle" by "square" and "area" by "side length" in my definition. I should say that the definition of $d(\cdot)$ is due to Eyal Shimony.

Comment: Dear Aryeh, Very nice question! Maybe it could help to remind what the Levi metric is?

Comment: Hi @GilKalai -- thanks for the suggestion. Done!

Comment: If you replace "area" with "height", you get the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic.

Comment: This d is not a metric.  Consider F, G and H, the cdfs of the distributions constant at 0, constant at 1, and uniform on [0,1].  Then d(F,G)=1 but d(F,H) = d(G,H) = 1/4.

Comment: @MattF. nice observation!